# List of objects always empty when passing to Domain Service method

Tags: silverlight-4.0, ria

I'm pretty much at my wits end here. I don't understand what I'm missing.

Here is my setup:

```
    [DataContract]
public partial class Class1
{
    [Key()]
    [DataMember]
    public string ID
    {
        get; set;
    }

    ...

    [Include]
    [DataMember]
    [Composition]
    [Association("FK_Class1ID", "ID", "Class1_ID")]
    public List<Class2> PierList
    {
        get; set;
    }

}

[DataContract]
public partial class Class2
{
    // This class has 3 values that make the key
    [Key()]
    [DataMember]
    public string Class1_ID
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [Key()]
    [DataMember]
    public int XID
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [Key()]
    [DataMember]
    public int YID
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public EnumType Type
    {
        get; set;
    }

    ...
}

[DataContract]
public enum EnumType
{
    [EnumMember]
    Val1,
    [EnumMember]
    Val2,
    [EnumMember]
    Val3,
    [EnumMember]
    Val4
}
```

In my domain service I have a save method:

```
[Invoke]
    public void SaveObject(Class1 object) { ... }
```

When I say object.ItemList, it is always empty. Even though it is set on the client, it is empty when I get here.

I have downloaded the SP1 Beta hoping it would fix my problems. It didn't. I have tried moving my list out into it's own wrapper class and passing it in as a second parameter (found [here](http://www.codemeit.com/wcf/wcf-ria-service-pass-array-list-or-collection-as-parameter-to-invoke-method.html)). I've tried making dummy get methods for my Class2 object as I've found suggested in other posts on here.

Nothing is working and I'm getting frustrated.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I feel like I'm just making random changes in hopes that something will work.

Thanks.

**Edit:** Ok, I've gone back to basics today. Here are my classes:

```
    public partial class TestClass
{
    [Key]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string ListID { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public partial class TestListClass
{
    [Key]
    public string ListID { get; set; }

    [Include]
    [Composition]
    [Association("TestListClass_ID", "ListID", "ListID")]
    public EntitySet<TestClass> TestList { get; set; }
}
```

This invoke method works fine, I can see all the properties: public void SaveTest(TestClass tc)

This invoke method doesn't work, TestList is null: public void SaveTest(TestListClass tlc)

I have added Insert/Update/Delete methods for both TestClass and TestList class.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: Just to clarify - your Class1 and Class2 objects originate from a domain service? or are they your own classes you are using RIA to transfer to your Silverlight client?

Comment: @Rus - they are my own classes that I'm using RIA to transfer to my Silverlight client.

Answer (score 0):

The blog post [here](http://tech.rofas.net/post/Working-with-associated-POCO-objects-in-WCF-RIA-Services.aspx) and [here](http://tech.rofas.net/post/Continue-working-with-associated-POCO-objects-in-WCF-RIA-Services.aspx) will help I think. It shows how to mark up the your objects to pass them over the wire.

I have put together a simple demo app which you can download [here](http://cid-7761748bb3825582.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/POCOTest.zip). The app shows passing a object with a collection of child objects from a Silverlight client across the wire to a RIA domain service.

Comment: I looked at your links and added in the Insert/Update/Delete methods in my domain service for the Class2 object. I ran again and nope. In my Silverlight app, I'm calling the save object like so: var save = _context.SaveObject(changedObject); When I call that, the PierList is populated. When I hit the breakpoint on the SaveObject method, PierList is empty. It's very frustrating that this list isn't going through. It's something you'd expect to be done without extra work. :(

Comment: Tyanna - I'm putting together a sample app that does what you're looking for. I'll have a link for you very soon.

Comment: thank you very much for your help! I've added an edit with what I've been trying today. Should be easier to follow (I hope).

Comment: Tyanna - Did the demo app help? Is your solution working now.

Comment: I didn't see your update or your reply here. Sorry! I haven't looked at your solution yet, but I will. I did find a way around it by adding a SaveItems method in my Domain Service that stored the list of objects in the session until I called the SaveObject method to save the parent object. It wasn't pretty but it worked.